# Disable RSS /feed/ endpoints on posts without disabling RSS overall

Tags: php, functions, actions, rss

I recently found that Google Search Console has picked up the RSS links for the individual posts and pages on a client site and is attempting to index them.  For example,  https://example.com/this-is-a-post/feed/ or https://example.com/about-us/feed/

I've found a number of plugins that will disable RSS for the entire website and a number of code examples that will disable RSS entirely for a given post type. What I'd like to do is keep the main RSS feed intact and just disable the /feed/ endpoint on all pages and posts. Even better would be to respond with 301 redirect request for those URLs to the post itself.

I've done a ton of googling and reading on WordPress' developer docs but have come up empty. Is anyone aware of a solution for this? I would definitely appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable feeds for specific custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88887/disable-feeds-for-specific-custom-post-types)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Indirectly, maybe.  I don't want to remove the entire RSS feed for posts and pages. I just want to remove the /feed/ endpoint and redirect related request to the original post/page.  I might be able to use the filter on rewrite_rules_array() and some regex to modify the rule that handles feeds but I'd have to figure out a way to do the redirect separately.  I'm hoping for a more direct solution but I'll definitely take a look at this. Thanks.